# Have the cart update with price, and then offer a coupon if subTotal is over $40

Tags: javascript, html

Working on a school assessment testing basic HTML design. I want to add a function that when you submit a quantity it will update the cart subtotal, and if that subtotal is larger than 40 it will give an alert signifying a discount code. I am new to javascript and coding in general so am struggling big time. I feel like I am so close but getting 'NaN' which I assume is because the id=quantity is not being fed into the function.

For the purposes of the assignment I would like to not use jquery, and php is not necessary.

relevant html:

```
<div id="quantity">
   <h4>How many people are coming?</h4>
   <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
   <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" pattern="[0-9]+" onchange="cartUpdate()" >
</div>  
<div id="cart">
   <p>Total Cost: <span id="subTotal"></span></p>
   <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Order">Submit Order</button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;


function cartUpdate() {
  var subTotal = (15 * quantity).toFixed(2) - 0 ; 
  document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "$" + subTotal;
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() { 
  if (subTotal > 40) {
  alert("Your ticket has been sent to your email. Since you have spent over $40, you are also eligible for a 20% off coupon for the snack bar which is included in your ticket.")
 }});
```

Comment: Try converting quantity into a number type using parseInt or parseFloat method.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and left out the html for the quantity form. I've added this now.

Comment: The `id` attribute MUST be unique in HTML to work this properly. You have the same `id` attribute for your `div` and for your `input` it is the same as well. Your code is picking up the first `id` attribute which is not a number input. Hence you are getting `NaN` on your total cost. Change your div from id to a class to -> `<div class="quantity">....` - Rest of your code works fine. Also, move the `quantity` var inside your `cartUpdate()` function

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you `NaN` instead of total because you have stored the value of `quantity` on a page load which is `undefined` at program start. To fix this get the latest value everytime value changes. See the code below it works as you expected.

```js
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
var subTotal = 0;

function cartUpdate(e) {
  subTotal = (15 * e.target.value).toFixed(2) - 0;
  document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "$" + subTotal;
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (subTotal > 40) {
    alert(
      "Your ticket has been sent to your email. Since you have spent over $40, you are also eligible for a 20% off coupon for the snack bar which is included in your ticket."
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="quantity">
  <h4>How many people are coming?</h4>
  <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" pattern="[0-9]+" onchange="cartUpdate(event)" />
</div>
<div id="cart">
  <p>Total Cost: <span id="subTotal"></span></p>
  <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Order">Submit Order</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That is main issue, even if he makes id unique then also his program will not work. due to stale quantity value

Comment: The code has multiple problems, but I agree that this is a valid solution. +1